# Javascript while loop weird behavior with dates

Tags: javascript, date

I am currently getting weird behavior from the following while loop in javascript.

```
var i = 0;
var endDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 6);

while (start <= end){
  alert (start.getDate());
  start.setDate(start.getDate() + i);
  i++;
}
```

The output I would expect (assuming today is Sept. 26) would be :

20
21
22
23
24
25
26

However I get the following output

20
20
21
23
26

I don't think I am handling the scope of the startDate variable correctly but I am not sure how to fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You're setting the date, which modifies it. On top of that, you're adding `i` to the date, which is incrementing. As such, the date that is set increases from the previous sets *and* the current `i`. Either create a date that remains unmodified, and add `i` to that, or just add `1` instead of `i`.  http://jsfiddle.net/gnmvao4n/

Comment: What are `start` and `end`?

Comment: I assume `start` and `end` are really just typos for `startDate` and `endDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming start and end are your date variables:

```
while (start <= end){
  alert (start.getDate());
  start.setDate(start.getDate() + i);
  i++;
}
```

Loop iteration 1: date is 20 and you add 0 => 20

Loop iteration 2: date is 20 and you add 1 => 21

Loop iteration 3: date is 21 and you add 2 => 23

Loop iteration 4: date is 23 and you add 3 => 26

To get what you expect, try this:

```
while (start <= end){
  alert (start.getDate());
  start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everybody basically gave the same answer but I think yours was the clearest.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterator is not correct. You don't really even need an iterator. Just add 1 instead of i to you second line of the while loop and delete var i = 0 and i++.

```
var endDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 6);

while (startDate <= endData){
  alert (start.getDate());
  start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
}
```

The reason why you are getting 20 20 21 23 26 is because on the first loop you are six days back, and add zero; the second loop you are six days back, and add one; the third loop you are five days back and add 2; the fourth loop you are now three days back, and adding 3; etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug through your code, you'll likely see each iteration of the loop you're modifying the date by a different value - `i` is changing each time through the loop. First time it updates the date by `0`, then by `1`, then `2`, etc. That's what you're seeing in the output.

Replace `i` with `1` and you'll get your expected output.  In fact, you don't even need `i`.